# Can't render a SKShapeNode with Texture and Path

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios9, skshapenode, sktexture

I have an SKShapeNode drawn on my scene with a CGPath. The strokeTexture is simply a circle.
On iOS8 it works perfectly. In iOS9 However it doesn't work at all unless I remove the texture part. 
Here is my code:

```
    SKTexture *pathTexture = [AtlasHelper getTexture:@"circle.png" fromAtlas:@"Common"];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath interpolateCGPointsWithHermite:pointsArray closed:NO];
    SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:[path CGPath]];
    shape.strokeTexture = pathTexture;
    [shape setStrokeColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    shape.lineWidth = 20;
    shape.zPosition = zOrderAbovePopUps;
    [self addChild:shape];
```

Notes:
1.Remove strokeTexture solves it but the path is being drawn without the texture (which is what I need)
2.Remove the stroke colour doesn't change anything
3.The result of this code is just a weird, blurry point :(

Help me please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
[shape setStrokeColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

With this :

```
shape.strokeColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Then your texture should be displayed normally.